# How do I interpret the slope coefficient of a variable expressed in percentage terms?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, cross-section

The regression is as follows:

Y - Crime rate per 1,00,000 of the population
X - Inequality : expressed as percentage of people living below the poverty line

In the data values of Y are the numbers of crime and X is the percentage i.e 28% or 17% so on.

My question is regarding interpreting slope coeff of X, do I interpret it as: 1% increase in Inequality increases the crime rate by Beta units or by Beta/100 units? or is there a different interpretation altogether.

I'm fairly new to statistics, so please excuse the poor language. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how $X$ variable is entered in the model - since it must have been entered as a number.

If it has been entered as 1 unit = 1% (that is, 28% appears as 28 in your dataset), the slope is the increase of the response when the predictor increases in 1% (that is, $X$ increases in 1 unit). When the predictor increases 1%, the response increases $\beta$.

However, if $X$ has been entered as decimal number (that is, 28% appears as 0.28 and 1 unit = 100%), then the slope is the increase of the response when the predictor increases 100% (again $X$ increases in 1 unit). When the predictor increases 1%, the response increases $\beta/100$.

In case of doubt I suggest checking the numbers in your dataset.