# How to Interpret regression slope when x is fraction and the step size is different?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, python, regression-coefficients

Let say I have two models where the "y" variable is some random variable and "x" variable is fractions in decimal between (0,1). In model one the x increases by 0.01 unit (e.g. 0.01,0.02,0.03...) and in model two the x increases by 0.001 unit (e.g. 0.001,0.002, 0.003...).

My question how to interpret the x coefficients of two models? According to [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260305/how-do-i-interpret-the-slope-coefficient-of-a-variable-expressed-in-percentage-t) if x is in decimal then the interpretation is "slope is the increase of the response when the predictor increases 100%". Is this interpretation correct for both slopes of model1 and model2? I mean the step size of increasing x doesn't matter?

In case it helps I created a little toy example in python:

```
# model one with 0.01 steps sizes
np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
X = sm.add_constant(x)
mod_ols = sm.OLS(y[1:], X)
res_ols = mod_ols.fit()
intercept_100, slope_100 = np.round(res_ols.params, 3)
>>>print(slope_100)
-0.011
>>>print(intercept_100)
0.511

# model two with 0.001 steps sizes 
x = np.random.rand(1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)
X = sm.add_constant(x)
mod_ols = sm.OLS(y[1:], X)
res_ols = mod_ols.fit()
intercept_1000, slope_1000 = np.round(res_ols.params, 3)
>>>print(slope_1000)
-0.047
>>>print(intercept_1000)
0.524
```

How do you interpret slope_100 and slope_1000?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you standardize your data and make it between [0,1], then you are not interpreting a percentage. This is one of the problems with doing such a thing, although sometimes necessary, as the interpretation of the values makes little sense.

You interpret `slope_1000` as follows; A 0.001 increase in X is associated with a -0.047 change in y, on average, after controlling for nothing else :).

Comment: Look at first reply here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47483/interpretation-of-the-regression-coefficient-of-a-proportion-type-independent-va My interpretation of this answer is the step size doesn't matter. So the interpretation of both slopes should be similar since x in both models ranges from 0-1. I might miss something here... it would be nice if there was some mathematical demonstration on why they are different or similar.

Comment: I mean you could talk about it being a 100% change, going from 0.001 to 0.002; but it feels a bit wonky.

Comment: Agree. However, I think in my specific case I go with 100% change for both models since it makes the interpretation easier to understand and more intuitive.